# Kube-Proxy with multiple external IPs

Tags: linux, centos, kubernetes, iptables

I would like to run multiple Kubernetes services and use the `externalIPs` field for those services to bind a specific service to a specific IP.

I have one VM which has three interfaces:

1. Internal interface (eth0)
2. External interface (eth1)
3. External interface (eth2)

I've already added iproute2 tables/routes/rules for the interfaces 2 and 3, which take care that the traffic is back-routed via the correct interface.

As long is kubelet/kube-proxy is not running, everything is working as expected. (e.g. running `nc` to serve some data.)

As soon a kubelet/kube-proxy is started some (and I don't know which) iptables configuration is created, which drops the packages.
(At least this is what it looks like in tcpdump.)

If I run only one IP on the node, everything works as expected - so I'm assuming the issue is the second IP and some kind of routing.

Here is the `iptables` config pre and post starting the kubelet service.
I've anonymised the file and removed stuff which is clearly unrelated - if I've removed to much, pleas let me know.

- https://gist.github.com/Thubo/7421d30288ef72ad480ac830dc19ec47

Does anybody run a similar setup?
How does one need to configure kube-proxy and/or the OS to setup this kind of network?
Any ideas where to proceed for debugging?

I'm running Kubernetes 1.6.4 on CentOS7.

Comment: Can you share iptables rulea which you have before an kube-proxy start and in time when you faced the problem?

Comment: also is there a specific reason you are using an ancient version of kubernetes? Te latest version is 1.9 and 1.10 is around the corner.

Comment: I'm aware that we are using an ancient version, but unfortunately updating is out of scope now - especially since it's not sure if it would help fix the problem. Apart from this issue, everything is working fine (and already running in production).

Answer (score 0):

`Kube-proxy` trying to manage all interfaces which it has, and, of course, forcing some rules (include filtering) for provide a service.

If you really want to use multiple interfaces on your servers and save custom forwarding rules between interfaces in the same time, you can bind all your components to the internal interface (`eth0` in you case) and manage all other interfaces manually as you want.

For set one interface, you should you that CLI args:

- For `kubelet` daemon - `--address`
- For `kube-proxy` daemon - `--bind-address`
- For `kube-api` daemon - `--bind-address`.

But please keep in mind, you will need to use that interfaces for all intercommunication inside a cluster and some flags, like `HostNetwork` will also provide you only that interface.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for:
My intention is to use those two external IPs (eth1 und eth2) to ingress traffic into my cluster and bind a specific service to this IP, while all the cluster internal traffic is handled through eth0.
I've tried to start kubelet with the --address on eth0, but this does not seem to do the tick.

Comment: You can do the same thing by just mapping your traffic from eth1 and eth2 to local eth0 using firewall, just map all ports you need 1:1.

Comment: I finally managed to find the bug.
Here the short answer version: I had a faulty default route for the internal network and I was missing default routes for the external network.
I still don't know why this became only an issue once I started the kube-proxy, but your answer pointed me in right direction for debugging.